# How to open React native app from external email link

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking

i use react Native, mongo,node,
i build full functions that worked and send email to user when he "forgot password",its worked perfect on postMan, **now the problem** is that i dont know how to implement that clicked on the email url open the app in "reset password" page.
i know something about deepLinking but how dont understand how to use it to open the app from email clicked.

```js
exports.sendEmail = emailData => {
    const transporter = nodeMailer.createTransport({
        host: "smtp.gmail.com",
        port: 587,
        secure: false,
        requireTLS: true,
        auth: {
            user: "roeigr7@gmail.com",
            pass: "iaoqymixqarajkbv",
        },
    });
    return transporter.sendMail(emailData);
};
```

and the data send to:

```js
const emailData = {
    from: "noreply@Lior.com",
    to: email,
    subject: "Password Reset Instructions",
    text: `Please use the following link to reset your password: ${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/resetpassword/${token}`,
    html: `<p>Please use the following link to reset your password:</p> <p>${process.env.CLIENT_URL}/resetpassword/${token}</p>`,
```

---------reset password FUNCTION:

```
exports.resetPassword = (req, res) => {
const { resetPassword, newPassword } = req.body;

User.findOne({ resetPassword }, (err, user) => {
    // if err or no user
    if (err || !user)
        return res.status("401").json({
            error: "Invalid Link!",
        });

    const updatedFields = {
        password: newPassword,
        resetPassword: "",
    };

    user = _.extend(user, updatedFields);
    user.updated = Date.now();

    user.save((err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: err,
            });
        }
        res.json({
            message: `סיסמא שונתה בהצלחה`,
        });
    });
});
 };`
```

--------- resetPassword component:

```
const resetPassword = async resetInfo => {
try {
    const response = await indexApi.put("resetPassword", {
        resetInfo,
    });
    console.log("forgot password response: ", response);
} catch (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data.error);
}
  };
const resetPassModal = () => {
return (
    <View style={{ marginVertical: 30 }}>
        <Text onPress={resetPassword} style={styles.titletext}>
            reset
        </Text>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I read in the React Native docs

> Like using the mailto scheme, it's possible to link to other applications by using custom url schemes. For example, when you get a Magic Link email from Slack, the Launch Slack button is an anchor tag with an href that looks something like: slack://secret/magic-login/other-secret. Like with Slack, you can tell the operating system that you want to handle a custom scheme. When the Slack app opens, it receives the URL that was used to open it. This is often referred to as deep linking. Read more about how to get the deep link into your app.

So im guessing when you compose your email you'd have a link like APP_NAME://ROUTE/TO/PASSWORD/RESET

Comment: Can u help me with that step by step? Cause i dont understand how to implement

Comment: I haven't used Linking much but if you give me some time I can come with something

Comment: if u want to talk in chat i will be thankfully with that

Comment: Im kind of new to answering questions on stackoverflow and I dont know how to start a chat

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226285/discussion-between-roei-grinshpan-and-myeongkil-kim